# Automate Button Click in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to automate below button click event without actually clicking the button..

Please give me a simple solution for this..

```
   private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0, aResult = 0;
        int[] aLen = new int[1];
        byte[] aUID = new byte[7];
        byte[] NbTg = new byte[1];
        byte[] RData = new byte[64];
        byte[] RDataLen = new byte[1];
        byte[] InitData = new byte[64];
        String ValStr = "";

        aResult = aResult = PN_InListPassiveTarget(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, InitData, NbTg, RDataLen, RData);
        if (0 == aResult)
        {
            for (i = 0, ValStr = ""; i < RData[4]; i++)
                ValStr += RData[5 + i].ToString("X2");
            textBox1.Text = ValStr;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Please Hold Your Meal Card");
    }
```

Comment: can u do this logic on page load? What should trigger this logic?

Comment: Can you give some details about automate here.?

Comment: u can actually fire this event artificially upon need

Comment: this code is for NFC reader.. when the NFC card near to the device and click the button. this event is work.. then the NFC card data read.. I need to run this button click event every 2 second without clicking the button..

Comment: Why not use a timer?

Comment: This is not work on web `MessageBox.Show`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer to initiate the event in 2 seconds intervals. You can put the NFC card reader logic in its own function and let the timer call that function from the first click until the card was successfully read:

```
using System.Timers;

public partial class MainWin : Form
    {
        public MainWin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Timer nfcTimer;

        private void buttonStartNFC_Read_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                nfcTimer = new Timer(2000)); \\ <- 2000 milliseconds is 2 seconds
                nfcTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(readCard);
                nfcTimer.Enabled = true;

                buttonNFC.Enabled = false; \\ u probably want to disable the button
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                print("Exception in :" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

You can put the NFC card reader logic here:

```
 public  void readCard(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e){
    // read card

    // failed to read the NFC card -> continue with the timer every 2 sec

    // The card was read successfully, you can disable the timer
    nfcTimer.Enabled = false;
 }
```

You can find more info about how to call a Button's Click Event Programmatically here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hkkb40tf(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: It is working.. but in the readCard method there is a textbox to  show the read data, when the card read there is a error came "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code"..

Comment: @HarshaEranga, nice to hear its working. As for the new error, can you post some of the code so I can take a look and might be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

If there is an event that will detect the card,  you can set a timer there to run after 2 seconds to execute this code. 
If you still need the code to run by button click too, move the code to a method and call it from both places.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a timer like this ? -

```
    // Create a timer with a two second interval.
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
    aTimer.Elapsed += button4_Click;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

The actual event handler signature for `Elapsed` event is this -

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

But `EventArgs` is a super class of `ElapsedEventArgs`, so you can use it just fine.